# MVC .Net web app - Combine web.config and global.asax - or deploy without web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a MVC .NET application. I thought I could deploy just web.config in the root folder. And of course also all the sub directories like VIEWS, etc. Oops. As soon as I copied the global.asax, it worked.

Is it possible to combine the web.config and the global.asax ? Then I can only have a web.config in the root directory.

Or, set up IIS differently ?  I am using IIS 7.5

Is there  e a way ?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to combine web.config? You can have more than one web.config nested in folders. Make use of it :) Will helpful to follow the separation of concerns :)

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can have a clean root, with only one file, that being the web.config file.    For interest, what kind of interesting things have you done in the nested folders.  One thing i can think of is that each _Area_ could have its own connection strings or settings ... but have you used for something more creative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do that, but here is some explanation with the hope it will help you in your decision:

**web.config** and the **global.asax** are completely two different things and have completely different rolls in ASP.Net applications.

**web.config**, as the name suggests, provides the necessary configurations for the application. It is required for the application to run.

**global.asax** provides events to control the application (e.g. `application_start`, `application_end`, `session_start`, etc). It is not strictly required, so you don't have to include it unless you need the functionality. MVC projects tend to have some code in **global.asax**, but it does not need to be that way. Depending on you application's needs, you may be able to move all the code in **global.asax** to somewhere else and then remove the file completely.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. I do have some custom mapping and assembly loading in the global.asax.cs, so I'll keep it around.  Thanks for that explanation.

Comment: @user2489945 By the way, I forgot to mention this: If all your code is the code-behind file **Global.asax.cs** and there is nothing in **Global.asax**, then I think you can safely exclude the **Global.asax** file from your published web folder (the content of the **Global.asax.cs** is compiled to the dll). I haven't tried that actually, so I don't know if there are any side-effects.

Comment: The only thing I have in there is this ...  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="inteVISTA.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: @user2489945 Yeah, that's always there as you know. So as I mentioned, if that's all what you have there, I think you can safely exclude the file from your published web folder. But again, I don't know if there are any side-effects.

Comment: If i remove it, the site just doesn't load.  But that might just be something special I do with the project and mvcContrib.  Thanks for the help.